# MySql Index better performance using a particular data type

Tags: mysql, indexing

Does the performance of mysql index depend on datatypes

If it does, what are the best datatypes to use in such cases?

Also, is it important to keep an index on a column which has less duplicate values or it is going to give the same performance even if applied on a column which has enormous duplicate values.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indexes aside, the best datatypes are the smallest ones to meet the domain requirements.

Column datatypes do affect the performance of indexes on those columns.

Smaller is better.

Indexes on integer columns work best (smaller, faster).

In a particular instance, the optimiser may chose not to use an index if it is not selective enough (i.e. column has many repeated values, and the value searched for, determined from statistics, will result in 'too many' rows.

- [How MySQL Uses Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html)
- [Data Type Storage Requirements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-requirements.html)

From the link @nani1216 posted:

> The size of the column or columns you’re indexing is relevant because
>   the less data the database server has to search through or index the
>   faster it’ll be and the less storage you’ll use on disk [or in memory]

Comment: So according to what you are saying, let me summaries it. Index work faster on columns with less duplicate values. I hope I've got it right?

Comment: not necessarily work faster (well that's the short answer), but less duplicates means an index will be more likely to be used

Answer (score 1):

Yes the performance varies with the use of datatypes.
Indexing on integer datatype gives you more performance than indexing on char or varchar datatypes.

Have a look at [What makes a good MySQL index?](http://webmonkeyuk.wordpress.com/2010/09/22/what-makes-a-good-mysql-index-part-1-column-size/)

Comment: Thanks, the link is helpful too

Answer (score 1):

As other pointed out, smaller data type is better. This is for simple reason - you can have more records loaded in the memory, if the record is smaller.

In InnoDB the primary key is the last column for each secondary index, so small primary key is extremely important for InnoDB tables.

As for the "selectivity" of index, the optimizer may choose not to use the index at all and do a table scan if the value match more than 50% of the records of the index (this is because, if the engine is InnoDB, the index is secondary and it's not covering index, it has to hit the disc once to read the index, and second time to read the actual row data, so it's better to read the table data directly. So you don't get much performance from an index on a column that contains largely the same values (but if small amount of the values are for example 0 and you are querying exactly for those rows, a index may be good!)